# Is there a If for to prepend or append in .Ajax?

Tags: ajax, jquery, append

```
 $.ajax({  
    type: "GET",  
    url: "../pgs/authenticate.php", 
    data: "FirstName="+ sFirstName +"&SurName="+ sSurname +"&NextOKin=" + sNOK ,  
    success: function(html){$("#Ajax_response").prepend(html);}    
        });
```

I only want to "prepend" IF the authentication fails else just:

```
  success: function(html){$("#Ajax_response").html(html);}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP script, you can do something like:

```
// on this part you decide based on your checks if it's true (or false)
// and what to return as content e.g. based on your authentication checks
$Success = true;
$Content = 'Some HTML';

$Response = array('Success' => $Success, 'Content' => $Content);
echo json_encode($Response);
```

in JS:

```
success: function(result)
{
   // if true
   if (result.Success)
      $("#Ajax_response").html(result.Content);
   // false (FAIL)
   else
      $("#Ajax_response").prepend(result.Content);          
}
```

I hope that gives you an idea.

Comment: where $Content is assigned to 'Some HTML', what do I do when the content is a php echo "hello world"; ? Looking forward to your reply

Comment: @SirBT, you would then put hello world to `$Content` e.g. `$Content = 'Hello World';`. Of course you need to make checks for the `$Success` variable if it's true or false.

Comment: @Tradyblix... Thank you. I cant seem to get  $("#Ajax_response").html(result.Content) or $("#Ajax_response").prepend(result.Content); to work. However $("#Ajax_response").prepend(result); works just fine. What am i missing?

Comment: @SirBT, did you do it like this? `$Response = array('Success' => $Success, 'Content' => $Content); echo json_encode($Response);` Also, add a JSON header at top most part of your ajax script, `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (html.match("/Failed/"))
{
$("#Ajax_response").prepend(html);
}
```

This looks for the word Failed in the Ajax response html and does the action if found. Obviously you know what the failure response will contain and what string you need to be looking for.

Comment: What if the Ajax response isnt a html but rather a php ech "hi";? Would this: (html.match("/Failed/")) still apply?

Comment: Yes. It will work on any string, as long as you change the word Failed to whatever you are searching for.